# How to change path name in mac bash?

Tags: bash

I want to change the path?(they are id?) in front of %, because they are too long to read.
I want to make them short.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`, using any editor you like, add one line

```
export PS1="<whatever prompt you like>"
```

Then restart the bash.